Pay Now Button with upi:// Link in HTML Email is Not Clickable
I'm creating an HTML email template with a "Pay Now" button that links to a UPI payment URL. Here's the code for the button:
<a href="upi://pay?pa=example@oksbi&pn=John%20Doe&tr=%20&am=500&cu=INR" target="_blank">Pay Now</a>

The button is styled and renders properly. However, the link is not clickable in Gmail, and it doesn't open the UPI payment app when clicked.
Interestingly, when I share the same link over WhatsApp, it works perfectly and opens the UPI payment app as expected.
Any work around for this issue?

I tested this in Gmail android, iOS, webmail and the link is stripped entirely. Apple Mail seems to leave the link but not sure whether it works. Outlook.com and Outlook apps strip the link. Yahoo webmail strips the link.
In the email world what they often use is a white list approach where everything that's not on the list will get removed. This means you're out of luck.
Can you go to a landing page first or otherwise via a browser which auto-redirects automatically?

Thank you @Nathan for the suggestion.
Can you suggest how can I redirect it through browser?

You could pass the information through the URL like ?info=text&other=moretext and then your website could pick that up and send it on to the app.
